# How do I programmatically access data about my database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, .net-4.0

I'd like to access the list of tables and for each table report number of rows, disk space used, etc. It would be nice to get these details at the database level, too.

How do I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just open a connection and query the database:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SYS.TABLES";
        using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
            while(reader.Read()) {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["name"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can Google for the query strings for the other information that you want.

Answer (score 2):

Jason's answer above is good, but more generally. you're looking at [Information Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx). Also Wikipedia's entry:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema

Answer (score 0):

Create a `SqlConnection` to your database and open the connection.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Servername;Initial Catalog=Marketing;Integrated Security=SSPI");
conn.Open();
```

Create a `SqlCommand` and assign the `CommandText` to the value of SQL you require.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PLACE SQL HERE", conn);
```

Tables and number of rows:

```
SELECT 
    [TableName] = so.name, 
    [RowCount] = MAX(si.rows) 
FROM 
    sysobjects so, 
    sysindexes si 
WHERE 
    so.xtype = 'U' 
    AND 
    si.id = OBJECT_ID(so.name) 
GROUP BY 
    so.name 
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC
```

Space used:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused 'tablename'
```

Answer (score 0):

This script doesn't include schema names but gets you most of the information you want for the current database. I'm sure you can adapt it into a stored procedure.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
DECLARE @tblSpaceUsed TABLE
(
    [name] sysname NOT NULL,
    [rows] int NOT NULL,
    [reserved] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [reservedKB] int NULL,
    [data] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [dataKB] int NULL,
    [index] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [indexKB] int NULL,
    [unused] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [unusedKB] int NULL
)

DECLARE @tableName sysname
DECLARE @tableNames CURSOR

SET @tableNames = CURSOR
FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT DISTINCT
    ss.name + '.' + st.name
FROM 
    sys.tables st
    INNER JOIN
    sys.schemas ss
        ON st.schema_id = ss.schema_id

OPEN @tableNames 
FETCH NEXT FROM @tableNames INTO @tableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tblSpaceUsed ([name], [rows], [reserved], [data], [index], [unused]) EXEC sp_spaceused @tableName

    FETCH NEXT FROM @tableNames INTO @tableName
END

CLOSE @tableNames

UPDATE 
    @tblSpaceUsed
SET
    [reservedKB] = CONVERT(int, LEFT([reserved], LEN([reserved]) - 3)),
    [dataKB] = CONVERT(int, LEFT([data], LEN([data]) - 3)),
    [indexKB] = CONVERT(int, LEFT([index], LEN([index]) - 3)),
    [unusedKB] = CONVERT(int, LEFT([unused], LEN([unused]) - 3))

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @tblSpaceUsed
```